# How to fix rendering of \date{\today} for devanagari articles using polyglossia?

Tags: polyglossia, date, indic

Consider a basic article using `polyglossia` and Devanagari fonts with `sanskrit` as the default language:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    bottom=20mm,
    left=10mm,
    right=10mm,
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguages{marathi,english}
% Main font for Sanskrit: Yashovenu
\setmainfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Yashovenu}
% Other font (for Marathi): Noto Serif Devanagari
\newfontfamily\marathifont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,Script=Devanagari,Language=Default]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
\edef~{\string~}
\author{dhura.mdhara.h bhaa.tava.dekara.h|}
\title {mama lekha.h|}
\date {04 ~ok.tobara, 2020|}
%\date {\today}
\maketitle

namo nama.h|
\end{document}
```

This renders just fine:

[image]

However, if I use (the currently commented out) `\date{\today}` or `\today` in favor of explicit specification of `\date` (as above), the rendering is wrong:

[image]

Is this a bug in `polyglossia`? Apart from the explicit specification of the date, is there any other workaround?